# How can we set both image and text to the navigation bar(iphone)?

Tags: iphone

In my application i want to set  image as background  to navigation bar and at the same i want to show date on left corner of thenavigation bar am able to set the background image to navigation bar but iam unable to put text on left corner of navigation bar any help.. Thanks in advance

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483921/how-can-i-change-the-background-image-for-my-navigationbar-on-a-per-page-basis

Comment: i used the code from the below url but text appears in the middle of navigation bar but i want to display in the left corner of navigation bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color

Comment: i got the answer to add text at the left corner of navigation bar just add subview to the navigationcontroller.navigationbar

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer to add text at the left corner of navigation bar just add subview to the navigationcontroller.navigationbar