# Change UINavigationBar background image to default - iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I change `UINavigationBar` background image with overloaded method

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Background)
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Header.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

But in some UIViewControllers I need to remove this background image. How I can do it?

Comment: Are you subclassing a UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at [this blog post from Sebastian Celis](http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/). It solves exactly the problem your facing.

And maybe also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483921/how-can-i-change-the-background-image-for-my-navigationbar-on-a-per-page-basis).

Comment: No, he explains how to implement UINavigationBar subclass and how to change UINavigationBar images in landscape and default modes. I know how to do this. I need to return UINavigationBar to UIBarStyleDefault. Simple method: self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
doesn't help

Comment: You need to subclass the UINavigationBar, not create a category of it

Answer (score 0):

test in this way

```
+ (void)setNavigationbarBackground:(UINavigationBar *)nBar imageName:(NSString *)imgName {
    if([nBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) {
        [nBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    } else {
        [nBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to customize my NavigationBar. I need to reverse this action

Comment: test in this way, works to me. [nBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: this is for iOS 5 :) I need iOS 4.x